# Validation loss having a sinusoidal wave form

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training an LSTM model on the [SemEval 2017 task 4A dataset](http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/index.php?id=data-and-tools) (classification problem with 3 classes). I observe that first validation loss decreases but then suddenly increases by a significant amount and again decreases. It is showing a sinusoidal nature which can be observed from the below training epochs.

[image: The training set]

Here is the code of my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 30, input_length=max_len))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

And here is the model summary

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 300, 30)           60000     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 300, 30)           120       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 300, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 300, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_2 (Bidirection (None, 64)                16128     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 64)                256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 76,569
Trainable params: 76,381
Non-trainable params: 188
```

I am using GloVe for word embeddings, Adam optimizer, Categorical Crossentropy loss function.

After changing the loss function and Dense layer, here is the training phase.

```
       Train on 16711 samples, validate on 1857 samples
Epoch 1/5
16711/16711 [==============================] - 55s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5976 - accuracy: 0.7456 - val_loss: 0.9060 - val_accuracy: 0.6182
Epoch 2/5
16711/16711 [==============================] - 54s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5872 - accuracy: 0.7521 - val_loss: 0.8919 - val_accuracy: 0.6144
Epoch 3/5
16711/16711 [==============================] - 54s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5839 - accuracy: 0.7518 - val_loss: 0.9067 - val_accuracy: 0.6187
Epoch 4/5
16711/16711 [==============================] - 54s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5766 - accuracy: 0.7554 - val_loss: 0.9437 - val_accuracy: 0.6268
Epoch 5/5
16711/16711 [==============================] - 54s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5742 - accuracy: 0.7544 - val_loss: 0.9272 - val_accuracy: 0.6166
```

Testing phase

```
 accr = model.evaluate(test_sequences_matrix, Y_test) 
    2064/2064 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step

print('Test set\n  Loss: {:0.3f}\n  Accuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0],accr[1]))
Test set
  Loss: 0.863
  Accuracy: 0.649
```

Confusion matrix

```
Confusion Matrix :
[[517 357 165]
 [379 246 108]
 [161  88  43]]
Accuracy Score : 0.3905038759689923
```

Classification report

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.49      0.50      0.49      1039
           1       0.36      0.34      0.35       733
           2       0.14      0.15      0.14       292

    accuracy                           0.39      2064
   macro avg       0.33      0.33      0.33      2064
weighted avg       0.39      0.39      0.39      2064
```

[image]

Confusion matrix code (I have imported **from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, classification_report**)

```
results = confusion_matrix(doc_test.response, Y_test) 

print('Confusion Matrix :')
print(results) 
print('Accuracy Score :',accuracy_score(doc_test.response, Y_test))
```

Comment: It's pretty standard to use ReLU, is there any specific reason you're using tanh?

Comment: Is it a classification problem? Which are the possible values of the labels?

Comment: @Pedrolarben yes it is a classification prboelm. Labels are +ve : 1, -ve : 2 and neutral : 0

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi no specific reason for tanh, but I used ReLU and it didn't give any better result too. Rather made it worse. Max Validation loss 95.5932 and min was -3.2638 and 14/20 epochs validation accuacy came a constant of 0.3317 (33.17%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have more than two classes you cannot use binary crossentropy. Change your loss function to categorical crossentropy and set your output layer to have three neurons (one for each class)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 30, input_length=max_len))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Anyway, from your training curves, I can see that the network is overfitting. It may be because of your data or because of your network. Check this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-overfitting-in-deep-learning-models-c760ee047c6e) to know more about overfitting in deep learning models.

This is the plot of the learning curve of your model. It shows a classical overfitting behaviour.
[image]

Comment: Changing the loss function and output neurons to 3 is working fine, but there's a problem with validation accurcy. Till 11 epochs (out of 20) it kept increasing but then for 2-3 epochs it fell by a good amount and then again increased. Whereas training accuracy is continously increasing and there's no issue with that. Even validation is increasing but in between it is showing this up and down nature.

Comment: Please, post a plot with the evolution of the training and validation loss so I can have a look better

Comment: I have added the training phase (with 20 epochs) in the question in the last. Please see.

Comment: I see now the validation loss increases in epoch 11, It may have two answers: (1) the model starts to overfit or (2) the validation dataset is not representative (it is very small or it is very different to the training distribution). As an advice, I would try with a simpler model (try just using an LSTM without batch normalization and dropout) and then continue making the network more complex so you can see how every layer affects the result

Comment: I have updated the training phase in the question. I removed batch normalization and dropout and the fluctuations in the validation phase seems to have gone after that (as oberved from training phase). But what I observed was that after 6th epoch validation accuracy became almost constant (62-63%) whereas training accuracy was increasing. This doesn't seems overfitting rather it seems my validation set is small. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: From the validation/training loss curve, I would say that the model is overfitting.

Comment: I saw the post regarding overfitting and added dropout layers in the model. The training phase is updated and I have also added my confusion matrix and classification report. From the testing phase, I got an accuracy of 64.7%. But the accuracy score as per my confusion matrix is 0.3905038759689923. I don't understand the difference between accuracy and accuracy score. It would be nice if you can guide me a little on this. I saw accuracy of other models with same dataset and the maximum was 65.1%. But I don't know if that was accuracy score or testing accuracy.

Comment: Please provide the results of your model trained 5 epochs, if you train it 16, you are getting worse validation results as it overfits. About the accuracy, where did you see the accuracy of 64.7%?

Comment: Added training phase for 5 epochs. I have also added testing phase below it which gives an accuracy of 64.9%. But the accuracy score shown after confusion matrix is 0.3905038759689923. Please have a look.

Comment: Please add the code you are using to get the confusion matrix. There must be something wrong we are not seeing. However, I think you should open a new question about the accuracy problem, as this question is pivoting from its initial meaning and it's getting too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215121/discussion-between-amber-bhanarkar-and-pedrolarben).